# How to use chessboard.js in Laravel blade templates

Tags: laravel, chess, chessboard.js

I want to make a chess game by using `chess.js` and `chessboard.js` in my laravel project. I am following the documentation of [chessboard](https://chessboardjs.com/examples#1004)

In the head section of my blade template I imported the library in a script tag as below:

```
<script>
        import ChessBoard from "chessboardjs";
        const board1 = ChessBoard("board1", {
            position: 'start',
            showNotation: false
        })
 </script>
```

And in the body section I made a div with id 'board1'

```
<div id="board1" style="width: 400px"></div>
```

Following is my complete blade template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        import ChessBoard from "chessboardjs";
        const board1 = ChessBoard("board1", {
            position: 'start',
            showNotation: false
        })
    </script>

</head>

<body>
     <div id="board1" style="width: 400px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am expecting to see chess board in the browser but nothing is displayed but an error in the console "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"
I also wrote script code in a separate js file and tried to import it but problem still exists.
Kindly guide how can I use chess.js and chessboard.js in my laravel/ vue project. Bundle of thanks

Comment: Hi, Did you add this chart.js using npm?

Comment: I also see it needs jquery to run. Have you added JQuery as well to your scripts?

Comment: @Charles Yes chessboard.js is added through npm. And I also added JQuery as well still It's not working. Is it the valid way to include node_modules in laravel blade templates?